# How in-memory databases store data larger than RAM memory in GemfireXD?

Tags: in-memory-database, hana, gemfire

If I am using a cluster of 4 nodes, each having 4GB RAM, so total RAM memory is 16 GB. And I have to store 20 GB of data in a table. 
Then how in-memory database will accommodate this data ? I read somewhere the data is swapped between RAM & Disk , but wouldn't it make data access slow. Please Explain

Comment: Is the [tag:sqlite] tag really appropriate for this question? I know SQLite supports in-memory storage, but so does MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, etc.

Comment: it is related to GemfireXD,it is also a in-memory data store.please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GemFire or GemFireXD `evicts` the data to disk if it feels memory pressure while accommodating more data. 
It may have some performance implications. However, user can control how and when eviction takes place. All the algorithms use Least Recently Used algorithms to evict the data.
Also, when a row is evicted, the primary key value remains in memory while the remaining column data is evicted. This makes fetching the row from disk faster.

You can go through the following links to understand about evictions in GemFireXD:
http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/1.3.0/userguide/developers_guide/topics/cache/cache.html

Comment: first time iam loading table data of  20GB into GemFireXD , how GemFireXD  will accumudate ? parelley GemFireXD will copy the data into disk?

Answer (score 0):

HANA offers the possibility to unload data from the main memory. Since the data is then stored on the harddisc, queries accessing this data will run slowlier of course. Have a look at the hot/warm/cold data concept if you haven't heard about it.

This article gives you additional information about this topic: http://scn.sap.com/community/bw-hana/blog/2014/02/14/sap-bw-on-hana-data-classification-hotwarmcold

Answer (score 0):

Though the question only targeted SQLITE & HANA wanted to share some insights on Oracle's [Database Inmemory](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/features/database-in-memory-option/index.html). It achieves loading huge tables into inmemory area by using various compression algorithms. Data populated into the IM column store is compressed using a new set of [compression algorithms](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/in-memory/overview/twp-oracle-database-in-memory-2245633.html) that not only help save space but also improve query performance. For example, table with 10GB in size when compressed with `capacity high` sizes to 3GB. This allows, table whose size greater than RAM be stored in a compressed format in inmemory area.

Answer (score 0):

The OP specifically asked about a cluster, so that rules out SQLite (at least out of the box).  You need a DBMS that can:

1. treat the 4 X 4GB of memory as 16GB of "storage" (IOW distribute the data across the noes of the cluster, but treat it as a whole)
2. compress the data to squeeze the 20GB of raw data into the available 16GB

eXtremeDB is one such solution.  So is Oracle's Database In-Memory (with RAC). I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your tables so, GemFireXD can use offheap memory to be able to store larger amount of data in memory, consequently pushing off the need to evict data onto disk a bit farther (although reads of evicted data are optimized for faster lookup because the lookup keys are in memory)

http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/1.3.1/userguide/data_management/off-heap-guidelines.html